# Can You Generate an Object With Property Names That Come from An Array?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a variable length array, such that each element of the array has some property:

```
var columns = [
    {
      field: 'state',
      label: 'State'
    }, {
      field: 'type',
      label: 'Type'
    }, {
      field: 'side',
      label: 'Side'
    }
]
```

I want to create a new object such that it will have a named property for each value of field in the array above, assigned to some value in another array (order):

```
row = {
                state: order[0]
                type: order[1]
                side: order[2]
}
```

But based on the original array, so it would be something similar to:

```
 row = {
                var i = 0
                for col in columns
                  row[col.field]: order[i++]
}
```

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var row = {};

columns.forEach(function(column, index){
  row[column.field]  = order[index];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You nearly did it:

```
var row = {};
columns.forEach(function(col, index) {
    row[col.field] = order[index];
});
```

Comment: If i want to add a single additional property that's not in columns, how would I do that using the code above?

Comment: @LazyCubicleMonkey: `row.additionalProperty = someValue;`. Learn more about objects from the MDN JavaScript Guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: You could initialize row with an object already containing this property property.